# How do I add a timer to a Jframe based Memory game in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, timer

I'm making a Memory-like game in Java using Netbeans.
I'm using Jframes for this.

I'm wondering how I would go about making a timer? It would start at 00:00 and count up seconds and minutes until all the couples have been found.

I'm still relatively new at Java. All the images in my game are made or edited by me. I don't own the character depicted and I'm not looking to sell it or something. It's just a fun little side project to learn Java a bit better.

I know my program is missing other features, but for now I'm only looking for help far this particular part of my game.

My game so far looks like this:

http://puu.sh/gkBlp/899525b31e.png
http://puu.sh/gkBA7/a1e75a5682.jpg

Comment: use java swing timer

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I don't see a "timer" option under the Jframe possibilities. I was thinking of just using a label instead. This is what I've got so far. It's a timer, but it doesn't have the format I want it to be.
mport java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


int timerCount = 0;


Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
timerCount ++;
jLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(timerCount));
}
}, 0, 1000);
}

Comment: Sorry, something went wrong white trying to comment.
http://pastebin.com/FQ2xes1v

Comment: you are setting a text on a lable .what are u trying to do actually?